# find the answer to a math question in python as a string?

Tags: python, math, calculator

I am making a calculator GUI, and I need to calculate the answers. All the solutions use three variables (num1, num2, operation). But I would prefer a way to solve other problems such as `1+1+1` with other methods do not do. I also store the problem as a string e.g `problem = "1+1+1"`.

Comment: Please share a [mre] of your current code and expand on exactly what you're trying to ask. The [ask] page might help.

Comment: If I were you, I'd record every new operation in a array which contains all operations with tuples of (value, operator). Afterwards you can select those tuples with multiplications/divisions to be executed before sum/subtraction

Comment: print(eval("1+1+1")) will output 3 as an int

Comment: You can evaluate an expression using the built in `eval` function. But be cautious by only allowing a string of numbers and operators that get passed into it. For example `eval("1+1+1")` will return an integer, 3.